# Is there a way to parse the Document AI OCR response into pdf format?

Tags: cloud-document-ai

I am passing scanned PDFs into the Google Cloud Document AI OCR. The JSON response (or the Document object returned when using the Python API) contains the content of the PDF in a structured format, as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1beta3/Document?hl=en_US#Page). I would like to be able to output a PDF file as well (or XML if that's easier). Is there such a functionality? Any hints on possible implementations are appreciated.

Note: the PDFs are already OCRed by another tool prior to my tasks, but the quality is not as good as the Document AI OCR.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing if anyone else is looking for this.
I found this repository [gcv2hocr](https://github.com/dinosauria123/gcv2hocr) which has a script to convert the Google Cloud Vision response (for image input) to hOCR format. The hOCR output can then be converted to other formats, including PDF using [hocr-tools](https://github.com/ocropus/hocr-tools).

I suppose it would not be very difficult to adapt this code to work with the DocumentAI response.

Comment: ocrmypdf is also a good solution. I have scanned documents as PDF, I want to convert it searchable PDF. Any idea how to do same with Document AI?

Answer (score 1):

Google's [Document AI Toolbox Library](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/toolbox) can convert it to hOCR or other formats but unfortunately not pdf.

here's hOCR example:

```py
from google.cloud.documentai_toolbox import document

def convert_document_to_hocr(documentai_document, document_title):
    wrapped_document = document.Document.from_documentai_document(documentai_document)

    # Converting wrapped_document to hOCR format
    hocr_string = wrapped_document.export_hocr_str(title=document_title)

    print("Document converted to hOCR!")
    return hocr_string
```